# How to fill Box with View?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm migrating from standard Android to Jetpack Compose but I'm having a problem. I don't know how to **"convert"** the following implementation:

Standard Android:

1. I call a function and receive a View.
2. I use the FrameLayout `addView()` method call to fill my `FrameLayout` with the received view.

How can I do it in composing?

In composing using a `FrameLayout` means to use a Box but I don't know how I can fill it with my received view.

Could anyone suggest to me the correct way?

here the code:

```
@Composable
fun MyCard(testActivity: Activity? = null) {
    AdvertView(testActivity) { view ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            AndroidView(factory = { view })
        }
    }
}
```

following where it's displayed the error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `List<View>` and loop over it. Adding elements into the list will trigger recomposition.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyOldFrameLayout(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, dynamicViews: List<View>) {
  Box(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    dynamicViews.forEach { view -> AndroidView(factory= { view }) }
  }
}
```

---

#### Based on what you provided on your screenshot

I suggest you refactor your screenshot into:

```kotlin
@Composable fun MyCard(onClick: () -> Unit) {
  Box(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    AndroidView(factory= { context -> AdvertView(context) { onClick() }  })
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it on OnClick action but I receive following error: The onClick parameter doesn't accept a composable function

Comment: Attach the callback before creating the view

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: I've updated my answer with all I think the problem might be given what you provided

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
)
```